# Xmpp message receive issue in Android

Tags: android, ios, xmpp, ejabberd, smack

I have added some extra attributes in xmpp stanza from ios device for date. Please check the below stanza.

```
<message type="chat" to="919930480045@devserver" id="919004883220@devserver-76" from="919004883220@devserver"><body>Heiok</body><date>2015-12-17 12:25:50</date></message>
```

But at android end I am not getting the value of the `<date>` element. I am getting the date element, but value I am getting is empty.

```
<date></date>
```

I have tried to pass the value as an attribute also. But same issue, Not getting the value for that. How can I customise smack library? or is there any other way to solve this problem?

I am using xmpp smack library version 4.1.

Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score -1):

you need to add date tag in ios as  `<body xml:lang='date'>2015-12-17 12:25:50</body>` and you can access in android as  `message.getBody("date");`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it is better to explain what it does and add some references to it.